# group an array of object by group name and children

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, grouping

I have an array of objects . I need to group this array by groups and children . I tried to create a new array with group names as keys and values as sorted array grouped by group, but didn't gave me the excepted format. How can I do this?

Below is my data format :

```
var data1 = [{
    "Name": "Apparel",
    "categoryId": 2742,
    "categoryName": "Men",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Fragrances",
    "categoryId": 2746,
    "categoryName": "Men",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Apparel",
    "categoryId": 2742,
    "categoryName": "Women",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Fragrances",
    "categoryId": 2746,
    "categoryName": "Women",
  }
];
```

Expected Output is :

```
var data2 = [{
    "categoryName": "Men",
    "children": [{
        "Name": "Apparel",
        "categoryId": 2742
      },
      {
        "Name": "Fragrances",
        "categoryId": 2746
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Women",
    "children": [{
        "Name": "Apparel",
        "categoryId": 2742
      },
      {
        "Name": "Fragrances",
        "categoryId": 2746
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I worked with this Function but the output is not as expected but am very close to the solution

```
function groupAndSort(array, groupField, sortField) {
  var groups = {}; // This object will end being keyed by groups, and elements will be arrays of the rows within the given array, which have been sorted by the sortField
  // Put all the rows into groups
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var row = array[i];
    var groupValue = row[groupField];
    groups[groupValue] = groups[groupValue] || [];
    groups[groupValue].push(row);
  }
  // Sort each group
  for (var groupValue in groups) {
    groups[groupValue] = groups[groupValue].sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[sortField] - b[sortField];
    });
  }
  // Return the results
  return groups;
}

groupAndSort(data1, "categoryName", "position"))
```

This is Output of that code :

```
{
  Men: [{
  categoryId: 2742,
  categoryName: "Men",
  Name: "Apparel"
}, {
  categoryId: 2746,
  categoryName: "Men",
  Name: "Fragrances"
}],
  Women: [{
  categoryId: 2742,
  categoryName: "Women",
  Name: "Apparel"
}, {
  categoryId: 2746,
  categoryName: "Women",
  Name: "Fragrances"
}]
}
```

I am very close to the solution I need just some help to make it as expected and thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of your groups object is the categoryName and the value is the children array so a simple mapping:

```
  // Return the results
  // return groups;
  return Object.entries(groups).map(([categoryName, children]) => ({categoryName, children}));
```

Comment: Works as expected , that's the right solution , thank you

Answer (score 2):

From where you left off, all you have to do is iterate through the object and push the key and associated array to a new final array.

```js
const data = {
  Men: [{
  categoryId: 2742,
  categoryName: "Men",
  Name: "Apparel"
}, {
  categoryId: 2746,
  categoryName: "Men",
  Name: "Fragrances"
}],
  Women: [{
  categoryId: 2742,
  categoryName: "Women",
  Name: "Apparel"
}, {
  categoryId: 2746,
  categoryName: "Women",
  Name: "Fragrances"
}]
}

const final = [];

for (const key in data) {
  final.push({
    categoryName: key,
    children: data[key]
  })
}

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the Object.values() of your grouped object

```js
const group  = {}; 

data1.forEach(({categoryName, ...rest})=>{
    group[categoryName] = group[categoryName] || {categoryName, children:[]};
    group[categoryName].children.push(rest)
});

const res = Object.values(group)

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
var data1 = [ 
          {
           "Name": "Apparel",
           "categoryId": 2742,
        "categoryName": "Men",
          },
          {
           "Name": "Fragrances",
           "categoryId": 2746,
             "categoryName": "Men",
          },
           {
           "Name": "Apparel",
           "categoryId": 2742,
             "categoryName": "Women",
          },
          {
           "Name": "Fragrances",
           "categoryId": 2746,
          "categoryName": "Women",
          }
         ];
</script>
```